# Rails Devise user_signed_in? method is not working despite user being signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, slim-lang

I've got the following code in my view file

```
- if user_signed_in?
  a href="/signout"
    li Sign out
- else
  a href="/signin"
    li Sign in
```

When a user is signed in I still only see the Sign in link; however, if I visit '/signout' route then I get the flash message that a user was signed out successfully.

How can I get this working so that when a user is signed in they see the sign out link?

Comment: This situation is a little bit different - I'll update the question with some more details

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to add the following to your controller:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers